# Assigning const int to a const pointer to int is illegal?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

Why is the following illegal?

```
extern const int size = 1024;

int * const ptr = &size;
```

Surely a pointer to non-const data should be allowed to point to a const int (just not the other way around)?

This is from C++ Gotchas item #18

Comment: "Surely a pointer to non-const data should be allowed to point to a const int" Why?

Comment: With a const-pointer to non-const thing, you can change the thing. If the thing is born const, that's undefined behavior.

Comment: "Surely a pointer to non-const data should be allowed to point to a const int (just not the other way around)?" -- You have it backwards. Surely a pointer to const data should be allowed to point to a non-const int, and it is. The `const` is about how something will be used, not what sort of thing it is.

Comment: Since you have `extern` in your post, I suggest you search Stack Overflow for "[c] extern pointer".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews does the extern affect the answer? It was in the example I saw so I just included it here.

Comment: Yes, `extern` does affect the answer.  Search Stack Overflow, as I suggested.  I asked a similar question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really meant one of

```
const int * const ptr = &size; 
const int * ptr = &size;
```

that is legal. Yours is illegal. Because it it wasn't you could do

```
int * ptr const = &size;
*ptr = 42;
```

and bah, your const was just changed.

Let's see the other way around:

```
int i = 1234; // mutable 
const int * ptr = &i; // allowed: forming more const-qualified pointer
*i = 42; // will not compile
```

We can't do harm on this path.

Comment: Explain the differences between the various const qualified pointers.

Comment: @Skizz: `const` applies to the item to its left: `int const* const` means “a constant pointer to a constant integer”; `int const*` means “a non-constant pointer to a constant integer”. As a special case, `const T` means the same as `T const`, so those are typically written `const int* const` and `const int*`, respectively.

Comment: @JonPurdy: I meant edit the answer to describe each one next to the example, just to clarify what each one means.

Answer (score 0):

If a pointer to nonconst data was allowed to point to a const int, then you could use pointer to change the value of the const int, which would be bad.  For example:

```
int const x = 0;
int * const p = &x;

*p = 42;
printf("%d", x);  // would print 42!
```

Fortunately, the above isn't allowed.